# How to create a multi image panel

Tags: jquery, html, css, user-interface

I'am trying to create a panel that looks like this, but i know that there is a technology that does this kind of panel, i'd like to know if any one knows. it has all this images and a video.
I've search for multi image panel, etc...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add styling technique using CSS.

Add some images to an element, then using `child-selector` or using classnames you can style them!

http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/39pKw/

You will require to use

```
img {
  display: inline;
  /* other styles if needed */
}
```

Then, using classnames you can edit the images to be shown as wanted!

Or the other idea is to create a single parent element and give it a simple style

```
.parent {
   width: 500px;
}
```

Then add images as its childs and then

```
.parent img {
  width: 30%; /* if 3 images; change it as required. */
}
```

This way, each image will consume some space and give some to the rest!